# Resizing HTML multiple full width videos with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, video

I know that it's possible to use CSS to make video full width on a page, but I am using a Javascript library to display the videos because it has some nice skinning and other functionality in the template I'm using. It works great for a single video but the template hard codes the resize to an ID tag and I'm struggling to get it to work with multiple, different videos with different ID tags. The second container doesn't resize. Here is the code:

```
    <section class="wrapper">
        <section class="full-width">
            <video id="video1" controls poster="img/poster.jpg" >
                <source src="media/sample.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
            </video>
        </section>
    </section>

    <!-- video2 markup is almost identical to video1 --> 

    function htmlVideo() {
        videojs("video1", {
          controlBar: {
            timeDivider: false,
            fullscreenToggle: false,
            playToggle: false,
            remainingTimeDisplay: false
          },
          "height": "auto",
          "width": "auto"
        }).ready(function() {
          var myPlayer = this;
          var aspectRatio = 9 / 16;
          function resizeVideoJS() {
              var width = document.getElementById(myPlayer.id()).parentElement.offsetWidth;
              myPlayer.width(width).height(width * aspectRatio);
              // I added these two lines but they don't work
              var width2 = document.getElementById("video2").parentElement.offsetWidth;
              document.getElementById("video2").width(width2).height(width2 * aspectRatio);
          }
          resizeVideoJS();
          window.onresize = resizeVideoJS;
        });

      // I added the following code as well trying to initialize the
      // video, but it doesn't work
      videojs("video2", {
        controlBar: {
        timeDivider: false,
        fullscreenToggle: false,
        playToggle: false,
        remainingTimeDisplay: false
      },
      "height": "auto",
      "width": "auto"
      }).ready(function() {
        resizeVideoJS();
    });
 }
```

Comment: In the line of code you added you are trying to call the `width()` method on a dom node. That method does not exist. In the line of code you copied, in contrast, the `width` method is being called on a player instance (`myPlayer`), which is a different object altogether than a standard dom node. I would read the library docs to see how to properly handle multiple instances.

Comment: Ok, that was helpful to realize that myPlayer and the video element were different. I made a global reference to a second video player and initialized that when video2's ready function gets called. It's not elegant, but now it's working. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome! I went ahead and dropped the comment in as an answer so that you can close the question if you got the info you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure that each player instance refers to a `player` object (as provided by the library), as opposed to directly referring to the `video` element dom node.